Importnig IDL schema into another avdl file
Working with avro IDL, i knew somehow i can import another defined record or enum in another file into the new file.
according to   this link  this can be done using the folowing code:
import idl "foo.avdl";

// blah

Btw, im trying avro-tools to check wether my IDL is fine, but when i use import, i face the following error:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.compiler.idl.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "include "" at line 1, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "protocol" ...
    "@" ...

The avro-tools works fine without the import part. So i was wondering wether i'm doing something wrong?
